# How do I run a video in a Div? iOS/iPhone (Prevent Fullscreen) &amp; Aviod apple's video loop glitch

Tags: ios, loops, video, fullscreen

I’m developing an iOS app with a looping video embedded into a div. I’ve got the “webkit-playsinline” working so it prevents apple’s fullscreen video player from kicking in… but there’s a glitch. As soon as the video begins its first loop, for some reason it forgets that its set to play inline and goes fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s my workaround in case this is frustrating anyone else out there:

```
<video class=“myVideo” width="640" height="360" autoplay webkit-playsinline>
<source src=“video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Rather than adding the “loop” attribute to the video tag, I use jQuery’s .on function to play the video again when it ends like this:

```
  var myVideo = document.getElementsByClassName('myVideo')[0];
  $('.myVideo').on('ended',function(){
myVideo.play();
$('.myVideo').attr('webkit-playsinline', ''); 
  });
```

I also reminded the video that we’re playing inline just incase it gets any funny ideas and tries to run in full screen mode on replay… viola! problem solved ;)